# How can I abstract the storage location of images in my HTML?

Tags: html, resources, abstraction

I am writing a web app which will store HTML in a database.  This HTML will have  tags which will point to images.  I am trying to think of a way to abstract the actual location of the images so that I can swap them out without having to update the text in the HTML.  Here is an example of what I mean:

```
<p>
    asdf asdf <img src="img.png" /> asdf asdf
    asdf asdf <img src="folderXYZ/img.png" /> asdf asdf
</p>
```

Ideally, the images here would be relative to some abstract "root".  I would like my webapp to populate the SRC value of the images with actual urls at runtime.  E.g. If I'm serving form Amazon S3, something like `http://s3.amazonaws.com/xxxxx/xxxxx/folderXYZ/img.png`, or if I change it tomorrow, maybe it comes from my local server `http://example.com/resources/folderXYZ/img.png`.

One thing I have considered is using a regex to pull out he IMG tags and manipulate them.  The other is making up my own syntax (maybe something like `{{IMAGE /folderXYZ/img.png}}`).  I dunno how this would be any different functionally, but it seems like maybe a good idea since these images aren't necessarily relative to the same server.

One other idea which occurred to me is that I could look up the actual resource in my webapp and stream the resource *from* that abstract SRC location, making my webapp a sort of "proxy" for the resources (wherever they are stored).  This seems great from a flexibility standpoint (the client doesn't have to see different URLs depending on the backend resource location) but is partially undesirable because it would put extra load on my server.

Just looking for suggestions.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to do this for everything on the page (images, CSS, Javascript, etc.), you could use the  element. Unfortunately that will apply to relative URLs in links as well.